How can I show product variant as a separate product on collection page in ella theme shopify without using any third party app?
I am trying to show product variant as a separate product on collection page in ella theme shopify without using any third party app?
I am looking to achieve this without using any code.
I tried googling on internet and was not able to get right resources.

Wouldn't a no-code solution make it off&topic on this site?
